# Spring Boot, Hibernate Data messes with my data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

So I have a web application using the Spring Framework.  I handle my data with hibernate and until now I havent had any problems.  I wrote a post fetch statement in JS and the data it returns is correct.  The data is an array of strings.  It returns the correct looking array, as in the correct order.  The problem is that when I view the data right after the array is in a different order.  Its so confusing because I dont even mess with the order of the array and I have no other fetch requests to the url path.  I have no idea what code to display here because my Java is a simple transfer object to saving into the real object.  The JS is a `fetch(url,{...}).then(response => response.json()).then(data(This displays the correct array order) => {});`.  Filled in correctly and all.  Its weird because the data it returns is correct but the data in the database is wrong.  Ive done this a few times before and for those instances ive never had problems.

Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editComment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Comment editComment(@RequestBody EditCommentDTO editCommentDTO) { 
    return commentService.editComment(editCommentDTO);
}
```

CommentService

```
    public Comment editComment(EditCommentDTO editCommentDTO) {
    Comment com = findById(editCommentDTO.getComId());
    com.setBody(editCommentDTO.getBody());
    System.out.println(save(com)); //Save goes to another function in the service that only executes commentRepository.save(com)
    return save(com);
}
```

Comment

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
(Extra stuff here such as id postId, userId)
@ElementCollection
private List<String> body;
(Getters and setters)
}
```

EditCommentDTO

```
public class EditCommentDTO {

private List<String> body;
private Long comId;

public List<String> getBody() {
    return body;
}
public void setBody(List<String> body) {
    this.body = body;
}
public Long getComId() {
    return comId;
}
public void setComId(Long comId) {
    this.comId = comId;
}
}
```

JS

```
console.log(stuff);  //stuff is an array of strings
  var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stuff));
  console.log(jsonArray);
  const data = { body: jsonArray, comId: comId};
  
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/editComment', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
    console.log(data); //Displays the correct data
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/getComments" function(cData){
      console.log(cData); //Displays the wrong data even though it should be the same as data
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    errorPlace(error);
  });
```

Comment: Are you posting any code or do you want people to guess what the issue might be?

Comment: I stated that I have no idea what code to display because the Java functions are just so small, I use a controller that talks to a service just saving an object.  I used that fetch statement above.  So I guess what I should be asking is if anyone came across this before.

Comment: It is like asking I have a `NullPointerException` and if anyone come up before. We don't know your entity class, controller and repository, and  what you have tried to resolve it, it is impossible figure out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added the code, literally no place of which I change up the array thats the reason why I felt like there was no need to display the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked on another place, a Discord server.  Someone showed me that `@ElementCollection` which is the annotation above my List body in Comment class does not keep the order of the array.  Add the annotation `@OrderColumn` and that should fix it.

Credit to LWJ for showing me the answer.